# Can I set on which monitor will application run through the Visual Studio appear?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, multiple-monitors

I am using multiple monitors and I prefer to have my Visual Studio open in the center one and I would like the application that I am testing / running through Visual Studio open on either left or right side, rather than on top of my code.

Do you think there is a way of doing that, that is automatic ? Can this be set somewhere in the options ?

I know that one solution is to change the main monitor to the left, but that would make all apps start on the left rather than in the center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The application is positioned by the OS and is not an option that you can set from Visual Studio.

Solution: It is simple to save the position of the application window on exit and restore it again on start-up (a [MSDN blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rprabhu/saving-out-a-forms-size-and-location-using-the-application-settings-feature)). Wrap it all in `#if DEBUG ... #endif` pre-processor so that it only occurs during development.

HTH,
Dennis

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and eventually thought of the now-obvious solution -- make the left monitor the primary....   ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, when connected to my work place with 2 monitors through RDP from a laptop. Visual Studio opened my app in the second monitor and I could not reach it. 
Win + Arrows helped me.