# How can I change the main monitor where Visual Studio 2013 launches a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8, and have 3 monitors.  Visual Studio is docked on the center monitor.  When I launch a WPF application via debugger, the program gets launched on the left monitor rather than in the center monitor.

After launching, if I drag the application to another monitor then stop, Visual Studio doesn't appear to "remember" where that application was last instantiated.  When I launch the app again it shows up in the center of the left monitor.

I saw a similar question from 5 years ago, but that was before Visual Studio 2013.  So I hope that Microsoft has improved this behavior, or someone has created a plugin which will enable me to set the launch monitor.
[Can I set on which monitor will application run through the Visual Studio appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482201/can-i-set-on-which-monitor-will-application-run-through-the-visual-studio-appear)

How can I make Visual Studio 2013 launch the application in my center or right monitor?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 4 monitors...if I want an app to run on a particular monitor, I position the mouse on that monitor and then hit F5. Has worked that way for me since VS 2005 through VS 2015.

The key, however is that your [`Window.WindowStartupLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to `CenterScreen`:

`<Window ... WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">`

> Setting CenterScreen causes a window to be positioned in the center of the screen that contains the mouse cursor

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, but if it works then this is an amazing trick! :)

Comment: That's the trick. I just set this in the window element of the xaml ala:  <Window ... WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">.  Thank you!

Comment: I did tried this but bad luck it didnt happen that way. I have 3 screens. My WPF application is a MahApps.Metro style.